# Spring Kafka OpenAPI v3 website generation + spec

Tags: java, spring-boot, openapi, springdoc-openapi-ui

Small question for Spring Kafka and OpenAPI V3 please.

In the paste, we had a Spring Web MVC web app, very straightforward, type https://interviewnoodle.com/documenting-a-springboot-rest-api-with-openapi-3-7b2bc1605f

```
package com.openapi.model;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
@Schema(description = "Book object")
@Entity
@Table(name="books")
public class Book {
  @JsonProperty(value="id", required=true, index = 10)
  @Schema(description = "Unique identifier of the Book.",
      example = "1", required = true)
  private long id;
  @JsonProperty(value="title", required=true, index = 20)
  @Schema(description = "Name of the title.",
      example = "Java", required = true)
  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 0, max = 20)
  private String title;
  @JsonProperty(value="author", required=true, index = 30)
  @Schema(description = "Name of the author.",
      example = "Max Abi", required = true)
  @NotBlank
  @Size(min = 0, max = 30)
  private String author;
  public  Book() {}
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  public long getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  @Column(name = "title", nullable = false)
  public String getTitle() {
    return title;
  }
  public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
  }
  @Column(name = "author", nullable = false)
  public String getAuthor() {
    return author;
  }
  public void setAuthor(String author) {
    this.author = author;
  }
}
```

```
package com.openapi.controller;

import com.openapi.model.Book;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Parameter;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Content;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.media.Schema;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponse;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.responses.ApiResponses;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.tags.Tag;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import java.util.Collection;

@Tag(name = "book", description = "the book API")
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/books")
public interface BookApi {

  @Operation(summary = "Create book", description = "This can only be done by the logged in book.", tags = { "book" })
  @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(description = "successful operation", content = { @Content(mediaType = "application/json", schema = @Schema(implementation = Book.class)), @Content(mediaType = "application/xml", schema = @Schema(implementation = Book.class)) }) })
  @PostMapping(value = "/", consumes = { "application/json", "application/xml", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" })
  @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
  public ResponseEntity<Book> postBook(
      @NotNull
      @Parameter(description = "Created book object", required = true)
      @Valid @RequestBody Book body,
      @NotNull @Parameter(description = "select which kind of data to fetch", required = true)
      @Valid @RequestHeader(value="bookAuthorization", required = true) String bookAuthorization)
      throws Exception;


}
```

For each and every client applications wanting to interact with us, i.e sending the http request with a Book object, we first jumped into a call, wrote a long mail explaning what the Book looks like.

Then, we discovered  `<groupId>org.springdoc</groupId> <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>` which changed the game.

We would just do the annotations, generate the Open API v3 doc as we build our project, no extra step.

We would then just send the spec.yml via email, and tell them "please go to http://the-cool-host:8080/v3/api-docs/, and you will be able to see what you should be sending us".

This worked like a charm.

For organizational reason, we changed the http based application to a Kafka based approach.

With that, we lost ability to generate the doc, and also, host it on a website.

What I tried:
I tried leaving the annotations, and running the maven clean install command to generate the doc, but it is not generating anymore.

May I ask what did I miss please?

What are the possibilities to generate the Open API v3 doc on the go, and host it, but for Spring Kafka please?

Thank you

Comment: Check out [AsyncAPI](https://www.asyncapi.com/) - it's like OpenAPI but for async and event-driven systems. I'm not sure if there's a Springdoc analog for AsyncAPI, but you can at least write an AsyncAPI definition manually and generate the documentation from it. https://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=4219

Comment: "Changing to Kafka" doesn't change how you can host OpenAPI webpage with Spring Boot... If you disabled the HTTP server, then that's a separate issue, and you'll need to add that back

Comment: You are correct @OneCricketeer, "changing to Kafka" means we are removing all wenflux/webmvc dependency in our SpringBoot project, leaving only kafka related packages. By doing so: we lost the capability to generate automatically the doc via the doc-plugin, as well as web handlers to access the doc within the same service

Comment: You should still be able to generate... But you'll need a separate web server to host that html/json spec

Comment: You should still be able to generate... -> tested not possible if web/webflux is removed